# Adding commas to a php number

Tags: php

Firstly, it seems this question has been answered before, however I can't seem to apply any of the answer to this version.

If I change the 19000 below to 19,000 the outputted form can't be submitted as it doesn't read as a number.

I heard I can use DecimalFormat but I'm struggling to see exactly where I put the line?

```
foreach($wb_spc_array['step1'] as $key=>$value){
  $array = array(
    "#type" => "textfield", 
    "#title" => $value['title'], 
    "#required" => TRUE, 
    '#default_value' => empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key]) ? '190000' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key],
    '#element_validate' => array('wb_spc_number_element_validate'),    
    '#size' => 20,    
  );
```

The full php module can be seen at (http://jsfiddle.net/ytv1v8r7/).

If it makes a difference this for a custom Drupal module, see [here](http://www.workbooks.com/sales-performance-calculator).

Many thanks for your time,

Comment: Why would you put PHP in the CSS box on jsFiddle... Use something like this instead - http://viper-7.com/FRqflG

Comment: Because I never knew that existed. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna try :

```
elseif($step == 1){
    $form['step1'] = array('#type'=>'fieldset', '#title'=>"Step {$step} (of {$section_count}) - Current Business Figures", '#attributes'=>array('class'=>array('step1')));

    $number = 190000;
    // english notation (default)
    $english_format_number = number_format($number);//190.000

    foreach($wb_spc_array['step1'] as $key=>$value){
      $array = array(
        "#type" => "textfield", 
        "#title" => $value['title'], 
        "#required" => TRUE, 
        '#default_value' => empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key]) ? $english_format_number : $form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key],
        '#element_validate' => array('wb_spc_number_element_validate'),    
        '#size' => 20,    
      );
      if(@$value['type'] == "percentage"){
        $array = wb_spc_form_element_select_percentage();
        $array["#title"] = $value['title'];
        $array['#attributes']['class'] = array("wb_spc_percentage");
        $array['#default_value'] = empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key]) ? '' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key];

      }
      $form['step1'][$key] = $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to hate me for this, but where exactly do I place this?

Comment: @Sam, just wrap it in **number_format()** function around where it gets used or displayed.

Comment: juste paste the above script in your php module

Comment: **EDIT** I spoke to soon. Unfortunatley It looks good but it won't lket me continue to the next step due to the comma (I believe it maybe a validation issue)? Any idea? The edited PHP can be seen at: http://jsfiddle.net/3gjx9aeL/

Comment: As I saw the code you pasted, you should remove the second `elseif($step == 1){ //statement }` line `179-201` remove this line ore comment.